# How to change bar chart value on each bar to custom value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, bar-chart

[image: MY bar chart looks similar to this]

Though I have values on the asp graph as attached, what I need is a different value to be shown on each bar.

For example instead of 5 on the bar graph I need to display 50 (instead of the label that displays 5).

What I would like to know is what property like the one below should i use in order to manipulate the label shown on each bar.

```
 Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 11f);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, not much time to elaborate 1- set IsValueShownAsLabel to false for your Series. 2 - iterate over your Series DataPoints and set their Label property

Comment: hey, but by any chance do you know what the property is? as in how to set the label property to a string or int value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for the label can be set as below:

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[counter].Label = "2";
```